# How to use images in a table?

Tags: tables, graphics

I want to use a table where the first column contains images and the second column contains text. Ideally the first column should have the width of the image and the rest of the pagewidth should be used for the second column.

So I tried to use this:

```
\begin{tabular}[htbp]{ll}
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{tag.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}l & History\\
  LS2 & Wegener\\
  LS8 & Morik\\
  LS10 & Doberkat\\
\end{tabular}
```

But when I try to generate a PDF I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.326   \begin{figure}[htbp]

?
```

Any hints how I can solve that? Thanks!

Comment: The `\begin{tabular}[htbp]{ll}` doesn't make much sense. You mean either `\begin{table}[htbp]` or `\begin{tabular}{ll}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the figure and the center environment. They make no sense inside a tabular. Use only the `\includegraphics` command