# How to use tabular/array to arrange figures

Tags: tables, floats, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use images in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/how-to-use-images-in-a-table)

I'm looking for a solution for automatic alignment of figures within my tex-file. I would like to keep it as simple as possible. I have the following idea but don't know how to implement it. Has anyone a suggestion?

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
%\hline
\begin{figure} \includegraphics{pic.eps} \end{figure} & \begin{figure} \includegraphics{pic.eps} \end{figure} \\
\begin{figure} \includegraphics{pic.eps} \end{figure} & \begin{figure} \includegraphics{pic.eps} \end{figure} \\
\begin{figure} \includegraphics{pic.eps} \end{figure} & \\
%\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Of course it would even be much more better, if I'd just type in the following and LaTeX will generate a two column table which will break automatically.

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics{pic.eps}
\includegraphics{pic.eps}
\includegraphics{pic.eps}
\includegraphics{pic.eps}
\includegraphics{pic.eps}
\end{tabular}
```

Here is how I would like it to be in the end

[image]

Comment: Hint: You don't need to wrap `\includegraphics` in a figure environment. In this instance you *don't* want images to float. You'll probably have to do the table manually though.

Comment: Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13240/9043

Comment: You get more horizontal space out of your `tabular` environment if you change `\begin{tabular}{ll}` to `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific width of your graphics (let's say about `.48\textwidth` or something like that, you might also use the `subfigure` package,
http://ftp.twaren.net/Unix/TeX/CTAN/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf
using the example 3.1 (page 15) using the package option `raggedright`. Advantage of this approach would be, that the other package options and vertical alignments, if you have 2 images of different height in one line. And of course - subfigure captions, which I really like.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is obsolete (the link you posted might have been a clue) and has been replaced by the `subfig` package. Another modern alternative is the `subcaption` package.  See [subcaption vs. subfig](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13625/2693) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Of course my idea also works with ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf (and yes i was a little lazy not looking at the URL), though i couldn't find the `raggedright` package option in there just now.